# Fragment Tabs menu opening a new activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, fragment, android-tabs

I have set up a tabs menu using fragments. This menu works fine. I can slide left and right to go onto different fragments. But when the user presses on a button I want him to go into a new activty with the tabs menu hidden. 
Just like they do with Whatsapp. In Whatsapp you have a tabs menu and when you for example press a chat you go into a menu where the tabs menu is hidden and you can press a return button to return to the tabs menu.

This is the code I tried:

The fragment class from which I like to start a new Activty

```
public class WeekFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "WeekFragment";
public static String selectedDay;
private ImageButton imgbtnMonday;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_week, container, false);

    imgbtnMonday = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_monday);

    imgbtnMonday.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (getActivity(), SwitchWeek.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return  view;
}
```

The Activity I need to open:

```
public class SwitchWeek extends Activity{
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
}
```

When I try to run this I get the message: "App has stopped working" as soon as I press the button in the WeekFragment class

Answer (score 0):

The tabs are in the layout. You just need to make sure that `R.layout.test` contains no ViewPager/TabView.

Comment: My test.xml contains nothing but an empty LinearLayout :(

Comment: @TimDriessen The layout is called test.xml, not text... Now assuming it was just a typo, are you adding a Viewpager in the new activity code?

Comment: How do you mean? In the ThermostatActivty class where I set up my fragments I created a ViewPager, but the Activity I want to open is empty (as shown above). Sorry If I misunderstood your question

Comment: I fixed the problem :). I forgot to mention my new activity in the androidmanifest xml file. Beginners mistake I guess. Thanks for your help